# Algorithm analysis for below function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have made a solution of chaining coin problem using recursion. I want to know to calculate the big oh complexity for this solution.

```
int chainingCoinRec(int val[], int p){
        int min=Integer.MAX_VALUE;


        if(p==0){
            return 0;
        }

        int i=0;
        while( i<val.length && val[i]<=p ){
            int temp=chainingCoinRec(val, p-val[i])+1;
            if(temp<min)
                min=temp;
                i++;
        }
        return min;
    }
```

Comment: I don't really know what sort of input you're providing to this function, but when I tried to put it together I got a stack overflow. Putting `int i = 0;` right before your loop means that the same parameters are endlessly being passed to calls to `chainingCoinRec()`.

Comment: No .. its working fine

Comment: For _you_, which I suppose is what matters. Good luck.

Comment: This program leads to an endless recursion if p cannot be represented by a sum of values in `val`.

Answer (score 2):

At each recursion level you have a loop with at most `val.length` iterations; lets call this `l`.

The recursion depth is at most p divided by the smallest element in `val` lets call this quantity `e`.

This means we have e nested loops, each running over l iterations.

The total effort is therefore O(l<sup>e</sup>).

Also note, that you are doing much more work here than necessary to solve the problem. You enumerate solutions that are basically equivalent because they only differ in the order of the coins.